# Problems with size of logo in the nav

Tags: html, css, templates, bootstrap-5

I have problems with bootstrap website template. I wanted to change width of the logo but that isnt working and I tried to change some things like max-width and more but this was useless, dont know how to do right way. What I want is to have bigger logo image and centered. I will be so grateful if someone can fix that.
Website template: https://technext.github.io/newbiz/index.html

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions must be self-containing and not rely on external resources. As such a link to your website, Fiddle or Git is not acceptable or suitable. Please add your debugging details in form of a [repro] (`Ctrl+M` or `<>`-button).

Comment: Your logo has a max-height applied so your width changes will have no effect.

Comment: So what I need to change to get good result? @NathanielFlick

Comment: Remove the max-height on the logo.

Comment: And how center logo image now in the nav? @NathanielFlick

Comment: To have bigger size of a logo in the nav and centered. But I dont know how to do that bcs almost nothing works